# Access of specific Folder in android and doesn't allow me to in

Tags: android, android-permissions

> I am getting the permission of a status folder

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun getFolderPermission() {
    val storageManager = application.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    val intent = storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
    val targetDirectory = "%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2F"
    var uri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI") as Uri
    var scheme = uri.toString()
    scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/tree/")
    scheme += "%3A$targetDirectory"
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,scheme,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    uri = Uri.parse(scheme)
    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses")
    intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1234)//content //com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2F
}
```

```
 @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val treeUri = data?.data

            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("DATA_PATH", MODE_PRIVATE)
            val myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit()
            myEdit.putString("PATH", treeUri.toString())
            myEdit.apply()
            if (treeUri != null) {
                contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                    treeUri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                )
                val fileDoc = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(applicationContext, treeUri)
                for (file: DocumentFile in fileDoc!!.listFiles()) {
                    if (file.name!!.endsWith(".nomedia")) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am try to ask for permission in specific path but emulator give me this error
Can't use this folder
to protect the privacy
I do not Know what is the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE20i.png)

[image: here is the image what I see]

Comment: You do not have access to app-specific storage of other apps on newer versions of Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare use this folder type access is require or not. Basically, i am accessing the status from that folder. Please also see attached img

Answer (score 0):

I was doing little mistakes
Here is the Right Code

```
   private fun openDirectory() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val sm: StorageManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
        val intent: Intent = sm.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
        val startDir = "Android%2Fmedia"
        var uri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI")
        var scheme = uri.toString()
        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "INITIAL_URI scheme: $scheme")
        scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/")
        scheme += "%3A$startDir"
        uri = Uri.parse(scheme)
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri)
        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "uri: $uri")
        startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE)
        return
    }
```